# confusion over access control declaration for variable and the class enclosing the varaible

Tags: xcode, swift, class, variables, access-control

The code below is legal in Swift, however, I was just wondering why `class Something` is not forced to be declared private. The reason why I'm saying that is because one of its variable, `private var anInstanceOfWhatever: Whatever = Whatever()`, is a private variable, if `class Something` is declared `internal` or `public`, I can use class Something outside the source file, but one of its variable can only be accessed within the source file, doesn't it create an conflict of some sort? Could someone please help me clarify the concept?

```
private class Whatever{

}

class Something{
    private var anInstanceOfWhatever: Whatever = Whatever()
    var number: Int = 0
    var text: String = ""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not create a conflict. If you used `Something` outside of the file, you simply wouldn't be able to access the property `anInstanceOfWhatever`, but you could access every non-private property or method.